# Is there an available English translation for Artin's "Quadratische Körper im Gebiete der höheren Kongruenzen"?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-fields, binary-quadratic-forms

Otherwise, is it reasonable to work through the German edition with only a basic knowledge of German?

Comment: I am not aware of any translation of these two papers (Part 1 is 54 pages long and Part 2 is 40 pages, probably you mean the first one). It would be trying with a little German, but worthwhile I think.

Comment: I've found that a machine translation and knowledge of the subject matter is more than enough to get through a paper in a language I have almost no education in (in my case it was French and German.)

Comment: Oh, I'll try that then. Thank you both! I can't upvote comments yet but I appreciate it.